# Windows 2000 and size MTU size for udp datagrams

Tags: windows, networking, udp, mtu

How would I change/make sure that my windows host receiver of multicasted udp datagrams is set to be able to receive an MTU of 1500? 
The documentation I've read so far refers to PPP and PPPoE, which doesn't seem to apply to udp datagrams.
Thanks
ak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPP/PPPoE are *not* mutually exclusive with UDP. The former are *link layer* protocols, the later is a *transport layer* protocol, see [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcp/ip#Layers_in_the_Internet_Protocol_Suite).

If you are talking about [ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) - you already have it. 1500 is the default ethernet MTU.

#### Edit 0

Then you usually don't work against ethernet directly. It's UDP (multicast), so subtract (at least) 20 bytes of [IPv4 header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure), and 8 bytes of [UDP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure). That gives you maximum of 1472 bytes for multicast data payload.

Comment: MTU is guaranteed to start at 576 I think the question is detecting end-to-end support above that, i.e. path MTU discovery.